# Get last child of given page by ID

Tags: wp-query

I've got the following code- I'm trying to get the last child page of a page with ID 4117. Here's my code thus far:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_parent'            => '4117',
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$posts = $query->posts;

foreach($posts as $post) {

    echo $post->post_title;

}
```

But it doesn't appear to do anything. Any clues as to what my issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

[`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) defaults to getting posts, not pages.

From the above reference page:

> Display content based on post and page parameters. Remember that default `post_type` is only set to display posts but not pages.

This code:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_parent'            => '4117',
    'post_type'              => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $query->posts;
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo $post->post_title;
}
```

...should do what you want.